# Why requestAniamtionFrame doesn't cause stack overflow error?

Tags: javascript, animation, stack-overflow, frame, requestanimationframe

I am trying to understand what happens under the hood of the browser when `requestAnimationFrame()` is called recursively.

I have ran code like this in my browser console:

```
function foo(){
    requestAnimationFrame(foo);
    console.log("foo");
}
foo()
```

**The result:** "foo" is being printend out non-stop.

**My problem:** I cannot figure out how I am not exceeding allowed stack size.

**What I think is happening**:

```
function callAsynchronously(callback){
    setTimeout(callback, 1);
}

function foobar(){
    callAsynchronously(foobar); // replacement for requestAnimationFrame
    console.log("hi");
}

foobar() // result is the same as before, non-stop printing
```

Above code is how I am visualizing `requestAnimationFrame`:

1. `foobar()` is put on the stack
2. `callAsynchronously(foobar)` is put on stack
3. `callAsynchronously(foobar)` popped from the stack
4. `console.log("hi")` is put on stack / browser apis put `foobar` callback into some queue after `setTimeout` is finished
5. `console.log("hi")` is popped from the stack
6. browser sees empty stack and puts callback from the queue on the stack
7. Repeat

I assume that `requestAnimationFrame` does something similar to not exceed allowed stack size but I am not sure if that's all there is to it. Also does it mean that I can bombard browser apis with async callbacks without getting any errors as long as I keep my stack size within acceptable range?

Comment: It doesn't run until all synchronous execution has completed. It schedules the given callback. Its not truly recursive, it just seems that way. Thats the nature of the event loop.

Comment: @zero298 ah, that makes sense. Post the answer if you want to and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` doesn't run until all synchronous execution has completed. It schedules the given callback. It acts very much like `setTimeout`.  Its not truly recursive, it just seems that way. Thats the nature of the event loop.

Answer (score -1):

`requestAnimationFrame` is called according to the refresh rate of the device screen. For example if you are viewing on 60hz screen the `foo` function will be called 60 times.

Comment: 60 times per second*. This is why I thought that it is very easy way to create stack overflow because one call each second generates at least 60 other calls which can scale really fast. I think @zero298's comment explains why there is no stack overflow errors.